# 12,10 ubuntu on usb for my thinkpad r50e

Tags: usb

i put the ubuntu 12,10 on usb for  my thinkpad r50e 
it s not working on my bios it s say the kemel requires the following features not present on the cpu 
pae
unable to boot .please use a kermel appropriate for your cpu 
what ineed to do 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is your CPU 32-bit or 64-bit? The i386 version of Ubuntu is for 32-bit CPU's and the amd64 version is for 64-bit CPU's. Make sure you have the correct version and if you're not sure then go with 32-bit!